# linq on nullable datetime

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that has Time1 and Time2 (for the sake of example). Time2 allows for nulls.

I have an object model and I want to have Time2 as nullable; so far I have this:

```
public Class MyModel{
   public DateTime Time1 {get;set;}
   public System.Nullable<DateTime> Time2 {get;set}
}
```

When I go to my query, I have this:

```
var MyQuery = ...
   select new MyModel()
   { 
      Time2 = (a.Time2)
```

and here I'm wondering if I should have the SingleOrDefault operator? It's not showing in the intellisense. Howver, the intellisense is showing several other options, amongst whic are: HasValue, Value, GetValueOrDefault.

Any ideas on what's the right one to choose from?

Thanks

Comment: You can use DateTime? instead of System.Nullable<DateTime>.

Comment: Are you sure you've included System.Linq?  If so, please post your entire query.

Comment: You can use DateTime? instead of the System.Nullable<DateTime>. It is ok as you are writing it, if a.Time2 is a DateTime or a DateTime?.

Comment: Do I just replace public System.Nullable<DateTime> with DateTime? in my object model definition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because Time2 is a nullable type. Nullable types always have a value property. If you revise your line to:

```
Time2 = (a.Time2).Value
```

and then press the period symbol after Value, you'll see the Intellisense pop up.

As a safety check you may want to also check that the value of a.Time2 is not null, before using .Value. Otherwise you'll get a null reference exception

Comment: Well sometimes Time2 will be null. How should I write this line? I changed the type to DateTime?; is this good?

Comment: DateTime? is equivalent to Nullable<DateTime>.

Comment: Yes but I get a "no explicit conversion between System.DateTime and <null>" right after the question mark with Time2 defined either as System.Nullable<DateTime> or as DateTime?

Comment: cast the null like this: (DateTime?)null

Answer (score 4):

SingleOrDefault is a extension method for the generic IEnumerable as you see below.

`public static TSource SingleOrDefault(
    this IEnumerable source)`

If you had some list of Nullable you could use that method and it would return the first value or throws if the list had none or more than one item.

```
//a list of Nullable<DateTime> with exactly 1 item
var listOfDates = new DateTime?[] { null };

var myDate = listOfDates.SingleOrDefault(); // myDate => ((DateTime?)null)
```

That is probably not what you want, you want some value when it is null, then you should use either the coalesce operator of C# 3.0 or one of the overloads of the GetValueOrDefault method from Nullable<> type.

```
DateTime? myNullDate = null;

DateTime myDate;
myDate = myNullDate ?? DateTime.Now; // myDate => DateTime.Now
myDate = myNullDate ?? default(DateTime); // myDate => DateTime.MinValue
myDate = myNullDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now); // myDate => DateTime.Now
myDate = myNullDate.GetValueOrDefault(); // myDate => DateTime.MinValue
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Time2 = a.Time2.HasValue ? a.Time.Value : null;
```

Comment: OK, and for the object model, should I keep it defined as System.Nullable<DateTime> or DateTime?

Comment: I get a "no explicit conversion between System.DateTime and <null>" right after the question mark with Time2 defined either as System.Nullable<DateTime> or as DateTime?

Comment: cast the null like this: (DateTime?)null

Comment: I use the DateTime? form everywhere.  It's easier to read and it doesn't have angle braces to hurt my eyes.

Comment: If I use .Value it returns a 'no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and 'null'.  It works without the .Value though.  This 5 years later though with C#6.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that You should have a method that exists for items of a collection on something that is a `System.Nullable<DateTime>`.

You won't have `SingleOrDefault()` on this.

`Time2 = (a.Time2.HasValue ? a.Time2.Value : null)`

That's how you should set the value or have it be null.

Comment: So what do I do? Do I choose GetSingleOrDefault?

Comment: @frenchie nothing, it will either be the Value or null. You may need to call the `Value` on the a.Time2().Value

Comment: Ok so I just write Time2 = a.Time2.Value? Will it throw an exception when it's null?

Comment: I get a "no explicit conversion between System.DateTime and <null>" right after the question mark with Time2 defined either as System.Nullable<DateTime> or as DateTime?

Comment: yea, you can `?` this apparently